# UML Sequence Diagrams and component relationships

Tags: jakarta-ee, uml, application-server, sequence-diagram

This came up in a discussion with a coworker as food for thought - what's the technically appropriate way to handle the relationship between components and sub components in a UML **sequence** diagram.

So here's the question - in UML best practices, should a sequence diagram have any connection to the relationship to the objects being described in the diagram?  My instinct would be no - draw a sequence diagram with each component separate and follow it up with class diagrams or deployment diagrams to show the other types of relationships in play.

If you say "YES!" please fill me in with some good examples of how and why you would do differently.

If "No", can you point me to some credible online references for justification?  I tried the UML spec and ... oy!  ... not what I wanted unless i was trying to beat myself unconscious.

In a specific, here was my example - I want to model a sequence diagram of how an application server calls a security plug in and then calls the basic application that has been deployed with JSP and Java.  The application server certainly "contains" the plugin and the application, but does that even matter for a sequence diagram?

In that situation would you just throw the three things up as 3 swimlanes with the app server as the brains of the operation, or would you do something different to show that neither the plugin nor the application would be doing much of anything in a standlone way?

Answer (score 1):

Well,

Both are valid....

It depends on for what purpose you will use your sequence diagrams.

```
> We draw a diagram since we have a purpose.... So Ask yourself which
> one help me more about solving my problem at hand? Which one is
> helpfull for my purpose?
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is distilling down what I know about the spec, what I have read, and experiences.

No.  A sequence diagram is to show behavior and the component relationship are part of the structure.  The UML spec and books are broken down this way, structure diagrams and behavior diagrams; [Wiki provides an image of this.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language#Diagrams_overview)  Some model elements like class etc are used in both, but relationships and composition really are not in this sense.  Besides, behavior diagrams are meant to show execution paths and are not typically "complete".  The structure diagrams and component relationships are more concrete and definitive in that sense.  You can always color code, use full names, or stereotypes to enrich view, but as far as the model is concerned and standard diagram notation no.

Answer (score 0):

There can be good reasons to include an element's "inner life" in a sequence. Sometimes you do want to provide as complete and detailed information as possible, for instance if you are submitting your design for a security review - then abstractions are no-go; you need to show precisely what's actually going on.

In other words, it isn't so much a question of UML best practice as of what exact information you need to convey to which specific audience.

Enterprise Architect from Sparx Systems allows you to include embedded elements (eg ports or provided interfaces) in a sequence, but in all honesty I don't know myself whether this is UML compliant or not. In any case, here's an example. Trivial, but you get the idea:

[image]
[image]